# R legend in base plot: how to fix size and overlap?

Tags: r, plot, legend

This sounds like a duplicate but my problem is more than only some size and position adjustments in `legend()`.

As a matter of fact, I did not tell R to make a legend so I have no idea where to adjust things. At this point, just being able to remove the legend would be a good start...

I'm modelling using package FME and currently reproducing [this example](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/FME/vignettes/FMEdyna.pdf)
but replacing the parameters and names with my own. I'm currently having problems with Local Sensitivity plots, they look like this:

[image]

But I never specified the legend. This is my code:

```
# model with differential equations - no instructions on plotting whatsoever
spi.phy.tom <- function(pars, state, times){}

# pars used in model (not really relevant)
test.pars  <- c(rIng = 0.5, rGrow = 0.26, rMort = 0.002,  
                assEff = 0.05, hSat = 0.5, K = 1000)

# sensFun calc sensitivity of variables to parameters
SnsSpint <- sensFun(func = spi.phy.tom, parms = test.pars, sensvar = "spint", varscale = 1)
SnsPhyto <- sensFun(func = spi.phy.tom, parms = test.pars, sensvar = "phytoseiulus", varscale = 1)

# output of sensFun are data frames
head(SnsSpint)
x   var rIng     rGrow rMort assEff hSat         K
1 0 spint    0   0.00000     0      0    0  0.000000
2 1 spint    0  28.62302     0      0    0  3.631926
3 2 spint    0  68.98759     0      0    0 10.053424
4 3 spint    0 122.48621     0      0    0 20.614181
5 4 spint    0 189.24599     0      0    0 36.986043
6 5 spint    0 267.46231     0      0    0 61.017033

# plot sensFun output
plot(SnsSpint, main = "Spint")
plot(SnsPhyto, main = "Phytoseiulus")
```

As you see, I didn't talk about legends, but I still get them. I always learned you need to specifically add `legend()` (with desired arguments) in order to get one. So I have no clue how to remove or adjust these ones.

*If you want to see the inside of the function, it's exactly the same as the one on p.2 of the pdf from the FME package (see link above). Didn't include it here because of too much irrelevant code.*

Comment: `plot()` is a generic function that does different things based on the `class()` of the object passed to it. It looks like the FME package creates it's one object class and put in a special print function for it. See what `class(SnsPhyto)` returns and see if there is a corresponding function for it in `methods(plot)`. It looks like they used `lattice` graphics rather than base graphics to draw their plots so the ways to draw legends are different than with traditional base graphics functions. There is probably a help page for that custom plot function.

Comment: Thank you, that's some new info for me. Certainly gives me a better understanding of the way things work. I'll look into those help pages!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `p+theme(legend.title = element_blank())` to remove title or `p+theme(legend.position="none")` to remove the legends or even change their positions to the top/right/left etc, by writing `p+theme(legend.position="top/right/left")`.
Regards;